# Function json_decode() throwing error while parsing response of Instagram API

Tags: php, json, instagram

This question has been asked many times and I've tried most of the solutions but nothing has worked for me.

I am trying to display most popular photos from Instagram on my website. I have manged to get the images from Instagram but I am not able to decode the response. Below is my code.

```
function makeRequest($url) {

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  //to suppress the curl output

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
            $response = json_decode($response, true);
        return $response;

    }

    print_r(makeRequest('https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'));
```

The above code gives "**JSON_ERROR_UTF8**" error.

I've tried following solution and it gives "**JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX**" error.

```
$response = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($response));
$json = json_decode(html_entity_decode($response, true));
```

I also tried following solution and I got "**JSON_ERROR_UTF8**" error.

```
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Can anyone please point out what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: The response can be found on the link below.

[Response](https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=9a73de768f5b4dbcb612fddc3ecc1baf)

Comment: Maybe post the json string you are trying to decode ?? You can also test it on http://jsonlint.com/ to find errors.

Comment: What is in `$response`?

Comment: @Andy Added the response.

Comment: try this: `json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` ( because of the arabic characters )

Comment: @Andy Doesn't work. When I try to use json_encode function it returns null.

Comment: I think he meant json_decode($response, true, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: yes, sorry i meant to say `json_decode` :D